# PHP: Echoing values of input fields

Tags: php

I am grabbing the values of several input fields with the help of an Ajax/JS function. The issue is that the values of the textbox are not being echoed. I checked with the firebug tool and it shows that the post is performed but there is a blank value. Why is the PHP not echoing the value when the JS function submits it?

[EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/TabsNextPrev/index.php)

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var timer = null;  
    var dataString;    
    function submitForm(){ 
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
            url: "index.php", 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(result){ 
            $('#special').html('<p>' +  $('#resultval', result).html() + '</p>');} 
        }); 
        return false; 
    } 
    $('#contact_form').on('keyup', function() { 
        clearTimeout(timer); 
        timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 2000); 
    }); 
});  
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contact_form" name="form4"> 
 <div class="row">  
  <div class="label">Contact Name *</div> <!-- end .label --> 
    <div class="input"> 
      <input type="text" id="contact_name" class="detail" name="contact_name" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['contact_name'])? $_POST['contact_name'] : ''; ?>" />  
      <div id="special"><span id="resultval"><? echo $_POST['contact_name'];  ?></span></div> 
    </div><!-- end .input--> 
 </div><!-- end .row --> 
 <div class="row">  
  <div class="label">Email Address *</div> <!-- end .label --> 
   <div class="input"> 
    <input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" />  
    <div id="special"><span id="resultval"><? echo $_POST['email'];  ?></span></div> 
   </div><!-- end .input--> 
 </div><!-- end .row --> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend first understand the Javascript behaviour. 
**When you post a form, it becomes one request to the server**. At the same time **when you send an ajax to server it becomes another separate request to the server**

So you should either do form post or ajax.

As you are using ajax here you, in the ajax request you have to pass data separately in data parameter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var timer = null;  
    var dataString;    
    function submitForm(){ 
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
            url: "index.php", 
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: $('#contact_form').serialize(), // check this line
            success: function(result){ 
            $('#special').html('<p>' +  $('#resultval', result).html() + '</p>');} 
        }); 
        return false; 
    } 
    $('#contact_form').on('keyup', function() { 
        clearTimeout(timer); 
        timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 2000); 
    }); 
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you friend, I am new to this and now I am starting to understand it thanks to your help. One thing that I am still having difficulty is echoing the value of each input field: `<div id="special"><span id="resultval"><? echo $_POST['contact_name'];  ?></span></div>`

Comment: If you want to use `<? echo $_POST['contact_name']; ?>` then ajax will not fill that for you, for that you will have to use without ajax. Make a simple form post and then it will work. Otherwise store `$('#contact_form').serialize()` data in some variable and after ajax success play with as you want. Hope you are getting

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on the form probably